# Trouble with onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery

Upon clicking the "Go" button, The blue square is meant to fade out. Once that is complete, a red square is meant to fade in. This doesn't happen.

Go

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (document).ready(function() {
        $("buttn#go").onClick(function() {

            $(".red").css("opacity", 0);
            $(".blue").css("opacity", 1);

            $(".blue").animate({opacity: 0}, 1000, function() {
                $(".red").show().animate(opacity: 1, 1000, function() {
                    var entered_name = $(".name").val();

                    $.get("./", {name: entered_name}, function(data) {
                        show_alert(data);   
                    })

                });
            });
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You forgot `$` in the very beginning, I've never seen a `<buttn>` element, JavaScript (and jQuery method names) are case sensitive

Comment: Did you ever have a look at the console, what errors do you see there? Are the above mentioned problems just typos?

Comment: Please put forth some effort to debug your code; learn about console and how to use it to solve basic syntax errors. We all make typos, but we also figure those put before seeking help.

Answer (score 1):

Couple typos and things here and there... think this should clear it up though:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#go").click(function() {
    $(".red").css({display:"block", opacity: "0"});
    $(".blue").css("opacity", "1");

    $(".blue").animate({opacity: "0"}, 1000, function() {
      $(".red").animate({opacity: "1"}, 1000, function() {
        var entered_name = $(".name").val();

        $.get("./", {name: entered_name}, function(data) {
          show_alert(data);   
        });
      });
    });
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Still not working. The go button is not doing anything

Comment: @Manish probably because the selector began with "buttn" which is not a known element. But since you've given it an ID (there should only be 1 on the page), can remove the element selector and just reference the ID. Check the updated answer. Also, as was noted above, you should check your console for errors and paste those errors here as that will probably tell you exactly why it's not working.